# python: writing to a csv file cell by cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to create a python game that relies upon a map generation. the problem is that, although I would be able to complete this, it will result in me having up to 100 variables.

basically, with the writerow method, I understand that it does it per row. as such, I would need to do the following (in pseudocode):

```
writerow(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5...)
```

as such, it is very undesirable, and will unnecessarily increase file size.

however, my question differs from others in that I only need to have the 'cell by cell' process once: when the initial generation of the map is performed. I also want to use the default csv library to do so. an example of the desired code would be as follows:

```
x = 0
y = 0
mapSize = 100

while x <= mapSize and y < mapSize:
    tileType = random("grass","water","desert")
    wrtiteCell(x,y): tileType
    x = x + 1
    if x = 101
    x = 0
    y = y + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

even if this you can't do this, you can add all items to a list, and then write it to the file:

```
list1=[]
while x < y:
    TILE = randomtile(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5)
    list1.append(TILE)
    x + 1
```